# Xcode 8.3 (iOS 10.3) Cannot launch simulated executable

Tags: swift3, ios10.3, frank, xcode8

My workspace has multiple targets one of which is unit tests.

When I run my unit tests from Xcode on iOS 10.3 simulator they all passed. However, when I test from command line i.e. by `xcodebuild` `<testtarget>` the tests are failing intermittently.

Following is the error message I see on the terminal

`xcodebuild[55631:340885] Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "Cannot launch simulated executable: no file found at /<Path>/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<ProductName>"`

This is happening only with Xcode 8.3 not earlier versions. 
I set `xcode-select` to 8.3.2 as well

Anyone ran into same issue?